# SQL Inner Join Two Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

I have two tables (`Users` and `Pairs`). The `Pairs` table contains 3 columns, an ID and then a user1ID and user2ID.

**Users**

```
ID      firstName      surname
------------------------------
1043    john           doe
2056    jane           doe
```

**Pairs**

```
ID       user1ID       user2ID
------------------------------
1        1043          2056
```

I'm then looking at using a select statement to get the user details base on the ID of the `Pairs` table:

```
SELECT users1.*, users2.*
FROM Pairs 
JOIN Users users1 ON Pairs.user1ID = users1.IDNumber
JOIN Users users2 ON Pairs.user2ID = users2.IDNumber
WHERE Pairs.ID = 1
```

Which returns the right details for the two users, however they're all on one row, how can I get it to return each user on a separate row as they are in the `Users` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT users1.*, users2.*
FROM Pairs 
JOIN Users
ON Pairs.user1ID = users.IDNumber
OR Pairs.user2ID = users.IDNumber
WHERE Pairs.ID = 1
```

Just use an OR statement in your ON condition instead of 2 joins.

Answer (score 0):

IN will work also.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Pairs p
        JOIN Users u ON u.ID IN (p.user1ID, p.User2ID)
WHERE   p.ID = 1
```